# Trojan TCP and UDP ports removal solution?

Tags: tcp

After a nmap scan on my local host on my Windows 7 machine results showed a vast list of open ports.

I'm using Windows Firewall. 
This machine was given to me by a friend. 
I've had my network crash occasionally.

How can I stop or close these ports?

Comment: Did nmap say anything else?  That's just a list of ports, it doesn't say what state they're in.  Also, scanning localhost may not give you a useful result.

Comment: When you suspect that the machine might be infected by one or more pieces of malware, the safest bet is always to wipe it and reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should check what is running on each port... or you can directly close them but you have to stop processes using those ports first... You can do this by using programs below or Google "how to close tcp/UDP port"...

You can also run nmap with -A which will output every info it can found about ports and system and process etc...

However, this may not be a Trojan but...some stupid way of handling ports... try using wireshark to listen your traffic...

[TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) 
[CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html)

Answer (score 0):

Run every virus scanner you can find on that windows machine (I suggest starting with malware bytes and clam win).. It could just be one virus trying to hide the post it's using to send and receive data or listening on each port to see which isn't filtered by your firewall/has port forwarding enabled on your router.. Orrr you have a ton of viruses (what websites has your friend been going on!?).. If nothing gets turned up in the virus scans run wire shark and see if any traffic is actually passing through those ports and what kind of data it is.. Check taskman as there has to be a nonstandard process running to have opened all these ports and have replied to the nmap scan. If all else fails post a list of the wire shark capture and process list and I'll take a look